# get second highest value from a dimension

Tags: tableau-api, data-analysis, tableau-desktop

click to view the image of the dataset

[image: 1]

here as we can see
there is a state , there is a election constituency , and then there are multiple candidates
who contested a election for the said constituency ....

now i want is to get the second highest vote acquirer in tableau ...
may be using calculated field or any other way ...
can you help please ?

i tried rank_dense() function but  i am struggling to plot the second highest value ,
i am missing something ....

Comment: You could use 2 calculated fields, the 1st one to calculate the rank, then the 2nd one to check if the 1st calculation = 2 then true

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Create a Parameter: "Nth Rank" with type as Integer and values as 1,2,3,4 etc

Step 2: Create a Calculated field: "Rank number" and put this formula

```
RANK(SUM([Votes Secured],'desc') = [Nth Rank]
```

Step 3: Show the Parameter as a dropdown

Step 4 : Drag the field "Rank number" in the filters pane and set to TRUE

Now, whatever Rank number you select from the parameter will display in the dashboard